# Why patricia trie for statically-sized variables?

Tags: storage-trie

I understand the value of a Patricia trie for key-value mappings. And, probably for dynamic arrays too. I also understand that Patricia trie in Ethereum is combined with Merkle tree properties, and the value of that. I also understand Merkle Patricia Tree is used for Transaction Trie mostly to only have to use one standard for "Merkling" ([source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/66752/125872)). But, I do not entirely see why Patricia trie is ideal for statically-sized variables, unless the reason is to only need a single standard (similar to the Transaction Trie case), and the Patricia trie is chosen because it *also* supports mappings and dynamic arrays. It seems to me like statically-sized data can easily be done with no trie at all, and just simple merkle tree from all "storage slots", since the number of data elements is typically fixed.

Edit: Double-checked in Remix, and apparently uninitialized statically-sized variables are not assigned storage slot. So, new storage slots are added to the tree even with the static data. Maybe that answers my question.